# HatchFilling in Mathemathica fills the entire are under curve

Tags: plotting, style, plot-themes, education, version-11.2

[image: The code is exact replica of the code present on the Wolfram site]
The Hatchfilling command is failing for me, i want to fill the area under the curve with vertical lines. If any suggestions plz do share. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reply to the comment**

```
filling1 = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, Sin[x]}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {1*#1 + 0*#2 &}, Mesh -> 80, MeshStyle -> Red, 
   PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> None];
filling2 = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, Cos[x]}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {1*#1 + 0*#2 &}, Mesh -> 80, MeshStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}], filling1, filling2]
```

[image]

Maybe work in your Mathematica version.

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
filling = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, Sin[x]}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {1*#1 + 0*#2 &}, Mesh -> 80, PlotStyle -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[plot, filling]
```

[image]

Comment: Worked. Thankyou!

Comment: If we want to add another function let's say cos[x], Can this code be transformed for it. Tried but Alas!

Comment: @SyedShahmirKazmi See the updated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `HatchFilling` is not available in your Mathematica. Which version are you using? This functionality was introduced in version 12.1.

You can get what you want using

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> HatchFilling[Pi/2]]
```

Comment: ok understood. Mine version is 11.2